# Functional Equation (no. of solutions): $f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 2f(x) + 2f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations, bilinear-form

Find all the functions $f\colon\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 2f(x) + 2f(y)$, for all rationals $x,y$.

Answer (score 15):

$f(0)=0$ By choosing $x=y=0$. Also by choosing $x=y$ we can see $f(2x)=4f(x)$. Moreover choose $x=0$ and use $f(0)=0$, then you have $f(y)=f(-y)$.

Now by strong induction one can prove that $f(nx)=n^2f(x)$.

Then choose $x$ as $\frac{x}{n}$ in preceding equation, then you get:
$$
f(x)={n^2}f(\frac{x}{n})\rightarrow\frac{1}{n^2}f(x)=f(\frac{x}{n})
$$
And finally we have:
$$
f(\frac{mx}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}f(mx)=\frac{m^2}{n^2}f(x).
$$
Now assume that $f(1)=a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then you get
$$
f(x)=ax^2
$$
for all rational $x=\frac{m}{n}$.

Comment: Indeed $f(\frac{m}{n})=\frac{m^2}{n^2}f(1)$.

Comment: Well, that was fine. I probably didn't read correctly. So I deleted the comment. However, I don't understand how you say *"Moreover choose $y=−x$ and use $f(0)=0$..."*. Putting that in the equation we get: $ f(0) + f(2x) = 2f(x) + 2f(-x) $. How do you say from this that $f(x) = f(-x)$?

Comment: Ok, understood. Excuse these silly questions!

Comment: You still can prove that the function is even with this choice by using $f(2x)=4f(x)$. Another option is to choose $x=0$ and then the answer is more direct.

Comment: $f(0) + f(2x) = 2f(x) + 2f(-x)$ with $f(0)=0 $ and $f(2x)=4f(x)$  gives $4f(x)=2f(x)+2f(-x)$ so $2f(x)=2f(-x)$ so $f(x)=f(-x)$

Comment: @Ouistiti, you can use $\text{ \text {the text here} }$ to display textual content within math. And as I said, I understood it already.

Comment: Thanks that will be much useful ! Sorry I did not see that comments changed !

Comment: How can you take $y=x=0$? What if it is a function of the form $f(x)=y$, so what if the point $(0,0)$ does not lie on the function?

Comment: Your solution is partially right, first prove that the point lies on the function, by taking $y=0$.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, Sorry your comment is not comprehensible.

Comment: Which one? I am just saying that how do you know that the point $(0,0)$ lies on the function we are looking for?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, I do not KNOW it. It can be simply derived that $f(0)=0$. Note that we know $0$ belongs to the domain. Have you seen the beginning of the answer "$f(0)=0$ By choosing $x=y=0$"?

Comment: @Arash That is what I am saying. Let there be any function g(x) satisfied by the condition. Is it necessary that the point (0,0) lies on it? Then how can you assume that before hand?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, No it is not! You have to prove it. Again, I have to ask you again: did you understand  the beginning of the answer "$f(0)=0$ By choosing $x=y=0$"?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, If you choose $x=0$ and $y=0$ as two "inputs" of the function $f$ in the above equation you get $f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)+2f(0)$ from that we get $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Okay wait a minute. Suppose there was any random functional equation and its solution was $ax^2+3$, then, if in beginning, you took $x=y=0$, then you wouldn't get **all** the answers.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, Ok,  I lost you. I do not really see how what you say can be translated into an argument related to the current problem. I hope someone else can help. Why $ax^2+3$ pops up here? The whole point of the argument is that for any function $f$ satisfying the condition of original problem $f(0)$ MUST be zero and hence it is impossible to have $ax^2$ as solution!

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal, I guess the proper way of arguing here is  to show what is wrong with my argument about $f(0)=0$. You can either point me to a flaw in the proof or give me a counter example (a function satisfying the functional equation and $f(0)\neq 0$.).

Answer (score 3):

That equation, which is often called Appolonius' formula or the parallelogram law, is a characterization of homogeneous quadratic forms on a vector space (without solutions of $v+v=0$).

In plane geometry, with $f(\mathbb{x})=|\mathbb{x}|^2$ the squared Pythagorean distance, the formula is the relation proved by Appolonius between the diagonals and sides of a parallelogram.  In a vector space, for any dot product [symmetric bilinear form] $B$, the associated 'squared distance' function [the restriction to a quadratic form] $f(x)=B(x,x)$ satisfies the equation, due to

$B(x+y,x+y)=B(x,x) + B(y,y) + 2B(x,y)$.

Conversely, any solution of the equation comes from this construction, and $2B(x,y) = f(x+y) - f(x) - f(y) $ .  The posted problem is the case of a 1-dimensional vector space over the field of rational numbers.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, one could, upon getting that $f(2x)=4f(x)$, keep differentiating both sides with respect to $x$;

$\quad 2f'(2x)=4f'(x), \\\quad 4f''(2x)=4f''(x), \\\quad 8f'''(2x)=4f'''(x),\\ \qquad \qquad \vdots \\ 2^nf^{(n)}(2x)=4f^{(n)}(x), \\ \qquad \qquad \vdots \\$

Then setting $x=0$, we have;

$\quad 2f'(0)=4f'(0), \\\quad 4f''(0)=4f''(0), \\\quad 8f'''(0)=4f'''(0),\\ \qquad \qquad \vdots \\ 2^nf^{(n)}(0)=4f^{(n)}(0),\qquad(1) \\ \qquad \qquad \vdots $

From this, it can be seen that $f''(0)$ can have an arbitrary value; with all the other derivatives being zero.

Using the Maclaurin's expansion for $f(x)$, we get the same answer as above;

$f(x)=ax^2\qquad$ (for some rational $a$)

Comment: who said it's differentiable