# if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., and if $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent, are $X$ and $Y$ normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Just recently come across Normal Distribution, and the following statement seems to be quite true, but is it? Can someone provide some general proof sketch if so please:

For X and Y identically and independently distributed with mean 0 and variance 1.

Suppose X+Y and X-Y are independent

Does it imply X and Y follow normal distribution?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4837/6633) on stats.SE for a generalization of this idea.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780236/tricky-probability-problem/780256#780256

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those assumptions imply that $X$ and $Y$ are normal, but the theorem is difficult. (In fact, you do not need to assume they are identically distributed; it is enough that they are independent.) It was proven by Sergei Bernstein in 1941. You can find a proof, and much more about characterizations of the normal distribution, in [this book](https://math.uc.edu/~brycw/probab/charakt/charakt.pdf). (Bernstein's theorem is proved in Section 5.1.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information about this proof but the book link is not available. Could you put the book name here? Thanks again!