# Variance of the minimum of two r.v.'s

Tags: probability, variance, order-statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

For two nonnegative independent r.v.'s, $X,Y$, with the same distribution and finite second moment, I'm trying to show that $Var[\min(X,Y)]\leqslant Var[X]$.

**Attempt 1.** For the continuous case, I've written the first and second moments of $\min(X,Y)$ in terms of $X$ but have no idea how to proceed with them. Specifically, with $Z=\min(X,Y)$, I have

$\mathbb{E}\left[Z\right]=2\mathbb{E}[X]+\int_{0}^{\infty}F^2_{X}(z)dz$,

$\mathbb{E}\left[Z^2\right]=2\mathbb{E}\left[X^{2}\right]+2\int_{0}^{\infty}zF_{X}^{2}(z)dz$,

(where $F_{X}$ is the cdf of $X$) but don't know what to do with the integrals in the RHS's of the above expressions.

**Attempt 2.** Noting that $\min(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}\left(X+Y-|X-Y|\right)$, I can write

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
Var\left[\min(X,Y)\right] & = Var[X]-\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X-Y\right|^2\right]+4\text{Cov}\left(X,|X-Y|\right)\right),  \\
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

but am struggling to show that the RHS's second term (1/4(...)) is less than or equal to zero.

Any suggestions about how I might proceed or confirmation these are dead-ends would be appreciated.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks for the response. Showing that $Var\left(X_1,\cdots,X_n\right)$ is nonincreasing for increasing $n$ indeed would be sufficient but I don't see how this is established in Lee David Chung Lin's answer to the linked post. If you have any insights into how it does establish this fact, please do share.

Comment: Great question, and I don't have a solution yet, but it wouldn't surprise me if you have to use the following trick: if $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Z = \min(X, Y)$ then
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(Z - \mathbb{E}[Z] \right)^2\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[(Z - \eta)^2 \right]\text{.}$$

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks for responding. Would you mind explaining how the equality you've provided above is true (or pointing me to where I can find out)?

Comment: @ben $$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(Z - \eta)^2] &= \mathbb{E}[(Z - \mathbb{E}[Z] + \mathbb{E}[Z] - \eta)^2] \\
&=  \mathbb{E}[(Z - \mathbb{E}[Z])^2] + \mathbb{E}[ (\mathbb{E}[Z] - \eta)^2]
\end{align}$$
The only part of this equality depending on $\eta$ is $\mathbb{E}[ (\mathbb{E}[Z] - \eta)^2]$, which is nonnegative and thus minimized when the expectation is $0$, or $\eta = \mathbb{E}[Z]$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Var(min(X,Y))=0.25 Var(X+Y-|X-Y|) = 0.25 (2Var(X)+Var(|X-Y|))-0.5 E((X+Y)|X-Y|)+0.5(E((X+Y)E(|X-Y|))$
$=0.5 Var(X)+0.25 Var(|X-Y|)-0.5 E((X+Y)|X-Y|)+0.5(E((X+Y)E(|X-Y|))$
Assume $E((X+Y)|X-Y|) \geq (E((X+Y)E(|X-Y|))$ which is true for uncorrelated RV as here $X+Y,X-Y$ are uncorrelated.
$\leq 0.5 Var(X)+0.25 E((X-Y)^2)-0.25 E(|X-Y|)^2$
$=0.5 Var(X)+0.25 (2 Var(X))-0.25 E(|X-Y|)^2  \leq Var(X)$

Comment: Thanks for the response. This resembles an attempt I made earlier today. But from what I can gather $X,Y$ independent does not imply $X+Y, X-Y$ independent (in general). https://math.stackexchange.com/a/782866/742588

Comment: Just because $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $|X+Y|$ and $|X-Y|$ need not be independent.  As in, for example, $X,Y$ iid $U[0,1]$.

Comment: Since we only worry about variance, uncorrelated would be enough ? which is true here.

Comment: I edited the proof.

Comment: @Balajisb Thank you! Just realised uncorrelatedness is sufficient.

Comment: I modified the proof to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\text{var}[\min\{X,Y\}]{=\text{var}[\min\{X,Y\}|X<Y]\Pr\{X<Y\}
\\+\text{var}[\min\{X,Y\}|X\ge Y]\Pr\{X\ge Y\}
\\=
\text{var}[X|X<Y]\Pr\{X<Y\}\\+\text{var}[Y|X\ge Y]\Pr\{X\ge Y\}
.
}
$$Assuming $\Pr\{X=Y\}=0$, due to symmetry we have $\text{var}[X|X<Y]=\text{var}[Y|Y<X]$ and consequently
$$
\text{var}[\min\{X,Y\}]=\text{var}[X|X<Y],
$$
which leaves us with an obvious inequality
$$
\text{var}[X|X<Y]\le\text{var}[X],
$$
since reducing the domain of a random variable also reduces its variance (a formal proof comes from definition).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I ask why the assumption of $Pr\left(X=Y\right)=0$? The rest makes intuitive sense.

Comment: Sure. I assumed $X$ and $Y$ be continuous, hence this probability actually is$$\int_{x=y}f(x,y)dxdy.$$Since $f(x,y)$ is continuous every where, integrating it over a line leads to zero answer.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I have an intuitive way to see why this inequality holds.

In fact, you can calculate the PDF of $Z$ to be $f_Z(z)=2f_X(z)(1-F_X(z))$.

It means:

$$\begin{align} f_Z &>f_X  & &\text{if} & z &< \mathrm{median}(X)~, \\
f_Z &< f_X  & &\text{if} & z &> \mathrm{median}(X)~. 
\end{align}$$

so, the density of $Z$ is more compact compared to density of $X$. Hence, the variance of $Z$ is lower.